# Increased performance of Azure Computer Vision on Docker

Tags: azure, docker, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Read API on my application to read a few lines of text on some labels and I have an average response time of 1s.
I know it is possible to install locally a Docker image (for security reasons etc) to perform the same operation, but what I'm more interested in is performance.

Has anyone used the Docker image locally on a relatively powerful computer, and managed to experience a performance gain on the same operations on the cloud?

Comment: There's no particular reason the same code would run faster in Docker than not.  There are a couple of reasons and configurations it could be slower.  Usually it will be about the same.  As with anything else performance-oriented, there's no substitute for actually running and measuring your application in your environment yourself.

Comment: No the comparison is not between Docker or not, it's between performance offered by Azure Cloud and Docker on a local server. There is no published metric on Azure Cognitive Services performances vs. same service on a local computer with docker, that would be very useful. How many cores/memory are reserved on the paid tier on Azure to get that 1s response time? What kind of server would I need locally to bring that 1s to 0.5s?  I can test, of course, but if anyone has already been there...

Answer (score 0):

By deploying Cognitive Services in containers, customers can analyze information close to the physical world where the data resides, to deliver real-time insights and immersive experiences that are highly responsive and contextually aware.

Containers do not cap transactions per second (TPS) and can be made to scale both up and out to handle demand if you provide the necessary hardware resources.

Here is doc for our container support documentation for additional details.
•   [Container Support in Cognitive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-container-support) - high-level overview of containers support.